# Efficient dictionary inversion on dictionary like file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

Been having trouble efficiently inverting (swapping the values for keys and the keys for values) a large (2.8GB) dictionary stored in a file. Efficiency is the problem, my current solution is to:

- Read the dictionary file line by line (format: ,,,...)

  For each line:

  - Run through the *in-progress* output file from the previous pass, copying it line by line to an temporary file
  - Insert dictionary values (val1,val2,...) where appropriate (alphabetically) into the temporary file with every new value being a new key
  - Overwrite the previous pass output file with the temporary file
  - Repeat until all dictionary lines are processed
    (ending up with format: :,,,..
    :,,..
    :,,,..)

This algorithm is very unwieldy, at the very least the output file has to be written over n^2  times (i think...) with n being around 30,000,000. Lack of available memory prohibits reading it in entirety and processing it all in memory.

There may be no better solution than leaving it to get on with it but if anyone had any thoughts it would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: Should have made clear each line finally outputted could contain multiple keys as values.

Comment: Have you looked into the [`dbm`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dbm.html) and related modules (`gdbm`, `anydbm`)?

Comment: I'm confused. Is each `<key>,<val1>,<val2>` line supposed to represent a key-value pair in the original dict, where the key is `row[0]` and the value is something like `tuple(row[1:])`? Are you trying to put `row[1]: row[0], row[2]: row[0], …` into the "inverted" dictionary, or `tuple(row[1:]): row[0]`, or something different?

Comment: @abarnert yes, your correct, the first row item is the key and subsequent items are the values for that key.

Comment: @senderle no, i have never heard of them although they do look promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following 3 pass solution:

1. Iterate over your original dictionary file once, adding a val, key line to your output file for each val as you go.
2. Sort the output file from step 1 using the unix sort command or some other fast sorting program.
3. If there is a possibility that step 1 produced duplicates that need to be removed, iterate over the output file from 2 and remove duplicates as you write your final output file.  Because the output file from 2 is sorted, you need only one pass and minimal memory to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, so let me describe what I *think* you want, with examples, then show how to do it.

Your input is a text CSV file like this:

```
a,1,2,3
b,4,5,6
c,7,8,9
```

Each row is a key, followed by a set of values. It represents a dictionary, where each value is a tuple—e.g., `d['a'] = (1,2,3)`.

The output should be a CSV file like this:

```
1,a
2,a
3,a
4,b
5,b
6,b
7,c
8,c
9,c
```

… but in some arbitrary row order. Each value from the original file is mapped to the key from column 0 in the row it came from. (If a value is duplicated, one key is chosen arbitrarily.)

---

So, if you were doing this all in memory, it would look like this:

```
in_dict = {'a': (1, 2, 3), 'b': (4, 5, 6), 'c': (7, 8, 9)}
out_dict = {value: key for key, value_set in in_dict.items() for value in value_set}
```

---

The only problem is that this will probably require on the order of 5.2GB of RAM to handle a 2.6GB dictionary, so you've got the in_dict stored on disk in your peculiar form, and want to write the out_dict to disk in similar form, without ever reading everything into memory.

The easiest way to do this is to use a DBM for intermediate storage. Read the CSV into a DBM—which then has exactly the same structure as `out_dict` above; it's just a bit more complicated to write it.

Obviously you'll want to use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html) module to read (and write) the CSV, and the [`dbm`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/dbm.html) (or, for Python 2.x, `anydbm`) module for the DBM.

```
with contextlib.closing(dbm.open('kv.dbm', 'n')) as db:
    with open('kv.csv') as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            for col in row[1:]:
                db[col] = row[0]
```

Then write that DBM out to your preferred format. If `dbm` objects had an `items` method, this would just be:

```
    with open('kvt.csv', 'w') as f:
        csv.writer(f).writerows(dbm.items())
```

Since they don't, you can either add one, or write a genexp:

```
        csv.writer(f).writerows((key, db[key]) for key in db.keys())
```

Or iterate explicitly:

```
        w = csv.writer(f)
        for key in db.keys():
            w.writerow((key, db[key])
```

---

You might also want to use [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tempfile.html) to make the DBM a temporary file that automatically gets cleaned up after you're done with it. Since the details are slightly different between Windows and *nix, and between Python versions, I'll leave that part as an exercise for the reader.